# Input element is not created after selecting a specific cell using nth child for row and column with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project that requires me to create an input element on a specific cell in the table. I have attached a screenshot to give you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

In addition, the table is an embedded code and all I can do is inspect its elements.

[image]

I have written the code below wherein it will check the cell in the first row under the second column and it will insert an input element.

```
<script>
var cellval = document.querySelector("table [data-cb-name='cbTable'] tr:nth-child(1) > 
td:nth-child(2)");
    if (cellval == "") {
        let var x = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "submit";
        input.name = "Mod0InlineAdd";
        input.value = "Add";
        input.class = "cbResultSetAddButton";
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

I have made my own research and checked similar issues as to what I have but nothing works with what I would like to accomplish. Can you help me understand why I am just getting a white space instead of an input button?

Comment: 1) `cellval` will never be equal to `""`. 2) You're appending to the body instead of at the cell's location. 3) What is `let var` supposed to mean?  4) Why are you assigning a `value` to the input twice?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you for taking the time to look into this

1. this is noted.
2. thanks that's definitely a mistake on my part thank you. 
3.  this is my first time to do a createElement I just followed the tutorial on w3schools.  Should I replace body with node?
4. it is a typo already edited value to class.

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML and CSS code to [demonstrate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and so that we can reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emc_tgn15 There should be no space after table in query selector and you cant directly add attributes to "input". Use className to add class attribute to element. The below script will work.

```js
var cellval = document.querySelector("table[data-cb-name='cbTable'] tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)");

    if (cellval.innerHTML === "&nbsp;") {    
        var x = document.createElement('input');
        x.type = "submit";
        x.name = "Mod0InlineAdd";
        x.value = "Add";
        x.className = "cbResultSetAddButton";
    cellval.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sivapagolu both of your codes work the only difference is that kishore's add button disappears when you move to the next page or when you do a search. Appreciate your time in taking the time to check my code and identifying my error. I will definitely take note of this to avoid getting the same error in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Insert your inputNode into the second row node(cellval), not into the body
and you have declared x as variable name and referenced input as your variable.

```js
<script>
    let cellval = document.querySelector("table [data-cb-name='cbTable'] tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)");
    let inputNode = document.createElement('input');
    inputNode.type = "submit";
    inputNode.name = "Mod0InlineAdd";
    inputNode.value = "Add";
    inputNode.class = "cbResultSetAddButton";
    cellval.appendChild(inputNode);
</script>
```